# Can python objects have nested properties?

Tags: python, object, nested, hierarchy, nested-properties

I have an object defined as follows

```
class a():
    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("hello from object.prop")
        @property
        def prop1(self):
            print("Hello from object.prop.prop")
```

When I call

```
>>> obj = a()
>>> obj.prop
hello from object.prop
>>> obj.prop.prop
```

I get the following traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_property.py", line 13, in <module>
    a.prop.prop1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prop1'
```

What I am trying to figure out is if I can define nested properties for objects?

Comment: The property would have to return the second property. Simply declaring the second property within the first doesn't make it an attribute.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: Returning a property object won't work. You need to return an instance of a class that contains a property object.

Answer (score 12):

The traceback is because your property doesn't have a `return` statement, hence it returns `NoneType`, which obviously can't have attributes of its own. Your property would probably need to return an instance of a different class, that has its own `prop` attribute. Something like this:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = b()
    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("hello from object.prop")
        return self.b

class b():
    @property
    def prop(self):
        print("Hello from object.prop.prop")

x = a()
print x.prop.prop
>> hello from object.prop
>> Hello from object.prop.prop
>> None
```

Comment: this is not the "nested property" asked in the question

Comment: @hago, I think it is actually. As it does achieve the goal trying to be achieved in the question. It also works for me, where I had a similar question as the orginal poster.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no, there's no way to wrap up the attribute access of an object other than yourself. Certainly there's nothing with a syntax that can be nested neatly (you can declare a class within your property function, but it gets ugly fast).

That is, in an expression like `obj.prop_a.prop_b`, the top level object `obj` can't directly control what happens with the `prop_b` attribute access, which is happening on a different object.

As an example, consider the following sequence of statements:

```
foo = obj.prop_a
bar = foo.prop_b
```

The value assigned to `bar` is the same as `obj.prop_a.prop_b`, but that statement didn't directly refer to `obj` at all.

If you're willing to get into the murky world of wrapper objects, it might be possible to do what you want, but it's not going to be as neat as a basic property. Like in @qwwqwwq's answer, you can have `obj.prop_a` return an an instance of a class with its own `@property` decorated function `prop_b`.

You could even declare the class inside of the `prop_a` function, if you weren't worried about it being accessible from the outside world. For anything complicated though, it will get messy fast.

Instead, consider if what you want to be accessible through `obj.prop_a.prop_b` could be better exposed through a property or method directly on `obj`, such as `obj.prop_a_b`. I suspect you'll find a much better design this way.

Comment: do you think that Style attribute and its properties could have been designed better without such  tricks in [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-style-attribute)?