# How can I type-hint a nested object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, zeep

I'm currently doing a integration with WSDL, and such decided to go with Python using the Zeep library.

I'm trying to model the response with `mypy`, so that it works with VSCode's Intellisense, as well as some giving me hints when I'm doing careless assignments or modifications. But I hit a roadblock when the WSDL responses is in a nested object, and I can't figure a way to type-hint it.

Sample response from WSDL:

```
{
    'result': {
        'code': '1',
        'description': 'Success',
        'errorUUID': None
    },
    'accounts': {
        'accounts': [
            {
                'accountId': 1,
                'accountName': 'Ming',
                'availableCredit': 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm using the following snippet to type-hint:

```py
class MethodResultType:
    code: str
    description: str
    errorUUID: str

class AccountType:
    accountId: int
    accountName: str
    availableCredit: float

class getAccounts:
    result: MethodResultType
    accounts: List[AccountType] # Attempt 1
    accounts = TypedDict("accounts", {"accounts": List[AccountType]}) # Attempt 2

client = Client(os.getenv("API_URL"), wsse=user_name_token)
accountsResponse: getAccounts = client.service.getAccounts()
accounts = accountsResponse.accounts.accounts


# Attempt 1: "List[AccountType]" has no attribute "accounts"; maybe "count"?
# Attempt 2: "Type[accounts]" has no attribute "accounts"
```

For Attempt 1, the reason is obvious. But after trying Attempt 2, I don't know how to proceed anymore. What am I missing here?

Update:
Following @Avi Kaminetzky's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59557637/1906623), I tried with following ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=f4450307f0a8ffb6f6285d145e63c014)):

```py
from typing import List, TypedDict, Optional, Dict

class MethodResultType(TypedDict):
    code: str
    description: str
    errorUUID: Optional[str]

class AccountType(TypedDict):
    accountId: int
    accountName: str
    availableCredit: float

class getAccounts(TypedDict):
    result: MethodResultType
    accounts: Dict[str, List[AccountType]]

result: getAccounts = {
    'result': {
        'code': '1',
        'description': 'Success',
        'errorUUID': None
    },
    'accounts': {
        'accounts': [
            {
                'accountId': 1,
                'accountName': 'Ming',
                'availableCredit': 1
            }
        ]
    }
}

print(result.result)
print(result.accounts)
```

But I'm getting error message from mypy:

```
"getAccounts" has no attribute "result"
"getAccounts" has no attribute "accounts"
```

Comment: The error you get have nothing to do with type-hints. You just trying to access dictionary keys as they are object attributes.

Comment: Yup, after few days and research, I figured the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914803) as reference, the following works for my case (Intellisense in VSCode, not working if directly assign into a variable):

Update: Using another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6993694) as reference, I have updated my code to be able to work both ways. (Intellisense in VSCode, directly assign into a variable)

```py
class MethodResultType:
    code: str
    description: str
    errorUUID: str

class AccountType:
    accountId: int
    accountName: str
    availableCredit: float

class accounts:
    accounts: List[AccountType]

class getAccounts:
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = accounts()
    result: MethodResultType
    @property
    def accounts(self):
        return self.accounts


client = Client(os.getenv("API_URL"), wsse=user_name_token)


# Getting real response from WSDL
accountsResponse: getAccounts = client.service.getAccounts()


# For testing using sample response
sampleResponse: getAccounts = getAccounts({
    'result': {
        'code': '1',
        'description': 'Success',
        'errorUUID': None
    },
    'accounts': {
        'accounts': [
            {
                'accountId': 1,
                'accountName': 'Ming',
                'availableCredit': 1
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 16):

*Updates derived from conversation in comments*

1. You will need each class to be a subclass of TypedDict. Something like `class Foo(TypedDict)`.
2. `errorUUID` is an `Optional[str]`.
3. `accounts` is type `Dict[str, List[AccountType]]` since it has an inner (perhaps redundant) key also called `accounts`.
4. You need to use square brackets with stringified keys to access the keys - `accountsResponse['accounts']['accounts']`.

Here is a proposed solution:

```
from typing import List, TypedDict, Optional, Dict

class MethodResultType(TypedDict):
    code: str
    description: str
    errorUUID: Optional[str]

class AccountType(TypedDict):
    accountId: int
    accountName: str
    availableCredit: float

class getAccounts(TypedDict):
    result: MethodResultType
    accounts: Dict[str, List[AccountType]]

result: getAccounts = {
    'result': {
        'code': '1',
        'description': 'Success',
        'errorUUID': None
    },
    'accounts': {
        'accounts': [
            {
                'accountId': 1,
                'accountName': 'Ming',
                'availableCredit': 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

See this MyPy playground: 
https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=dad62a9e2cecf4bad1088a2636690976

TypedDict is an extension to MyPy, make sure to install MyPy (plus extensions) and import TypedDict: `from typing_extensions import TypedDict`.

From Python 3.8 you can import TypedDict directly from the typing module.

https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/

Comment: The python version I'm using is Python 3.8 and I already having Mypy installed. 
If I subclass getAccounts(TypedDict), I can't even type-hint `result` properly ("getAccounts" has no attribute "result"). Please note that in sample response, `accounts` is a nested object. Can you provide a sample code on how would you do it?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, using your example, I will get 2 error messages: 1. `"getAccounts" has no attribute "result" 2. `"getAccounts" has no attribute "accounts"`

Comment: It worked for me here https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8

Comment: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=f4450307f0a8ffb6f6285d145e63c014

I have tried the website, and including the playground that has the error message

Comment: See this link: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=80d462e1db7dfa04c2f152b8cb557956

Comment: Thanks, but the example that you provided doesn't type hinting correctly, because whenever I try to access the `result` or `accounts` attribute, mypy would report error (as per my link)

Comment: You need to access the keys with square brackets and stringified keys: `result['result']`, since TypedDict is treated like a regular dictionary not a class variable (which can be access with dot notation). I updated the mypy playground link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205300/discussion-between-avi-kaminetzky-and-tan-jia-ming).