# Type hints for recursive and varying length objects in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm having trouble getting a correct type hint to satisfy mypy.

The function takes a dict[str, List], such as:

```
input = {"group_1": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
          "group_2":['d', 'e', 'f'],
          "group_3":['g', 'h', 'i']}
```

The function creates an object that will be used by another function to fill the empty lists according to some other logic.

```
def create_output_object(input: dict[str, List]) -> ?:
    output = {}
    groups = [k for k in input.keys()]
    for group in groups:
        if group not in output:
            output[group] = {'from': {}, 'to': {}}

    for k in output.keys():
        for group in groups:
            if group != k:
                if group not in output[k]['from']:
                    output[k]['from'][group] = []
                if group not in output[k]['to']:
                    output[k]['to'][group] = []

    return output
```

The output of `create_output_object(input)` looks like:

```
{    
     'group_1': {
                 'from': {'group_2': [], 'group_3': []},
                 'to': {'group_2': [], 'group_3': []}
                },
     'group_2': {
                 'from': {'group_1': [], 'group_3': []},
                 'to': {'group_1': [], 'group_3': []}
                },
     'group_3': {
                 'from':{'group_1': [], 'group_2': []},
                 'to': {'group_1': [], 'group_2': []}
                },
     'new_products': [],
     'removed_products': []
}
```

A solution like the one in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498869/how-can-i-type-hint-a-nested-object-in-python) looks promising.

However, the output will not always have the same number of groups or group names. For example, with one less group it would look like this:

```
{
    'group_1': {
                'from': {'group_2': []}, 
                'to': {'group_2': []}
               },
    'group_2': {
                'from': {'group_1': []}, 
                'to': {'group_1': []}
               },
    'new_products': [],
    'removed_products': []
}
```

The error I'm getting from mypy is

> Need type annotation for "output" (hint: "output: Dict[<type>, <type>] = ...")

Comment: Please add your type hints.

Comment: I've added some more detail about the function and type hints

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845024/defining-a-recursive-type-hint-in-python

Comment: You didn't add the type hint for the output that's causing that error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, as far as I can tell.

### Simple `dict`s and `Union`s

```py
from typing import TypeAlias, Union

D: TypeAlias = dict[
    str,
    Union[
        dict[
            str,
            dict[str, list[object]]
        ],
        list[object]
    ]
]
```

This matches the example outputs you provided, but does not enforce any specific keys to be present in any of the dictionaries. Also, the values at the top level for example could be *all* dictionaries, no lists, and it would be fine with this type. For example these would *also* be fine with that type definition:

```
y: D
y = {'a': []}
y = {'x': {}}
```

---

### Pre-defined keys with [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class GroupLists(TypedDict, total=False):
    group_1: list[object]
    group_2: list[object]
    group_3: list[object]


FromToGroups = TypedDict(
    'FromToGroups',
    {
        'from': GroupLists,
        'to': GroupLists,
    }
)


class TopGroups(TypedDict, total=False):
    group_1: FromToGroups
    group_2: FromToGroups
    group_3: FromToGroups


class TopDict(TopGroups):
    new_products: list[object]
    removed_products: list[object]
```

Here I assumed that the keys `new_products` and `removed_products` must always be present in the top level dictionary, but any of the `group_` keys may be missing. This is enforced due to `TopDict` inheriting from `TopGroups`, which is defined with `total=False`.

Also this enforces both `from` and `to` keys to be present in those sub-dictionaries, however the sub-dictionaries can have any number of the predefined keys.

Note that I had to use the functional notation to define `FromToGroups` because one of the keys is a reserved name in Python: `from`.

Of course this forces you to know in advance, which keys *may* be present in that dictionary. That is in the nature of a `TypedDict`.

But that `TopDict` type also works with your provided example outputs.

---

In addition, I would say you can also use a mix of those two approaches, depending on your needs.

Hope this helps.