# Is there a way to set attribute to sub objects in a class?

Tags: python, object, attributes, nested-object

I would like to be able to do this:

```py
>>> obj = Example('hi', 'hello')
>>> obj.a 
'hi'
>>> obj.sub_obj.b
'hello'
```

I try this but I get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'b'`:

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.sub_obj = {} 
        self.sub_obj.b = b
```

I see a similar question but I don't understand much: [Can python objects have nested properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17914737/3416774). I just want the output JSON is to have nested objects. The API requires me to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add custom methods/attributes to built-in Python types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698493/can-i-add-custom-methods-attributes-to-built-in-python-types)

Comment: Do don't add attributes to dicts, you add keys.

Comment: What's the purpose of adding custom attribute to an instance attribute that is empty dict? This may well be a XY problem or misunderstanding as pointed by @KlausD.

Comment: @buran I just want the output JSON is to have nested objects. The API requires me to do so

Comment: You add to a dictionary with `[]` syntax: `self.sub_obj['b'] = b`

Comment: JSON formats dictionaries as objects.

Comment: @Barmar nice trick. Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: This is such basic Python syntax, there must previous questions that already answer it.

Comment: _I just want the output JSON is to have nested objects. The API requires me to do so_, so this is indeed XY problem/misunderstanding how dict works.

Comment: @buran indeed, since I'm still new to Python. But thinking again, being able to call nested valued like `obj.sub_obj.b` is neat and help debugging better

Comment: You can have a look at [How to use a dot "." to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352181/4046632). I personalty would stay with regular dict. Also you should distinguish between attribute access and access to members of collection/mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is a dictionary, so assign to its keys the normal way, with `[]` syntax.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.sub_obj = {'b': b} 

    def update_b(self, new_b):
        self.sub_obj['b'] = new_b
```

Comment: why is the attribute a dictionary but not a regular object?

Comment: Because you assigned `{}` to it. That's an empty dictionary.

Comment: I think you may be confusing Python and JavaScript. JS uses `{}` syntax for object literals, Python uses it for dictionary and set literals.

Comment: do you know why isn't there a unified connotation across languages?

Comment: @Ooker, What, in your opinion, is "unregular" about the `dict` object?

Comment: Because that's what makes languages different.

Comment: @buran Presumably the fact that it doesn't use `.` to access elements.

Answer (score 0):

Objects created by literal syntax will continue to be of the vanilla type and won't have your new methods/attributes.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Python doesn't have literal syntax for objects. I think you're confusing it with JavaScript.